# Reduction of elliptic curves over local fields

Tags: elliptic-curves, rigid-analytic-geometry, p-adic

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over a p-adic local field $K$, with $j$-invarient $j(E)\in K$. Let $\mathscr{O}_K$ be the ring of integer of $K$. If $j(E)$ does not belong to $\mathscr{O}_K$, then $E$ is isomorphic to a Tate curve $\overline{K} / q^\mathbb{Z}$.

I am wondering if $j(E)\in \mathscr{O}_K$, is it true that:

> $E$ has potentially good reduction over $\mathscr{O}_K$?

Comment: Yes. Proposition VII.5.5 in Silverman's Arithmetic of elliptic curves.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Got it, thank you!